# Flexslider in Magnific Popup Ajax Popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup, flexslider, magnific-popup

I am using Magnific Popup (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) and want to open another file via Ajax. In the ajax file, I have a Flexslider (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) Gallery which should show some images.

Everything works normally (the flexslider on the hompepage loads normally) and the ajax popup opens too. But the slider *inside* the popup is not showing up (I think its not initialized somehow).

JS

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#home-slider').flexslider({
  //Options
});

$('#portfolio-slider').flexslider({
  //Options
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="portfolio-slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="img/portfolio1.png"  alt="Description" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/portfolio2.png"  alt="Description" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I think I am missing something, but I don't have any idea what...

Answer (score 1):

An old question but anyway. Since the window has already loaded, you need to wrap the code instead in $(document).ready(function() { }); and include it inline within the container you are loading into the Magnific Popup (if any, otherwise somewhere in the page). You can specify the Magnific container by using the parseAjax callback:

```
    $('.ajax').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        cache: false,
        callbacks: {
            parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
                mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#some-element');
            }
        },
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        // More options
    });
```